# how to control the order of the Childs added and submitted to a parent in Linq to sql in C#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

so the problem is i have been coding on a project,in this project a bill of sale which is table A has 3 products which are represented by table B in our concept.
logic states that when i add product 1,2 and 3 to the object that represents table A,they should be inserted as added,i.e it should be as : 
Table A Children => 
1,
2,
3

however in some of our forms in the project it works differnetly,somtimes i see the children are submitted as 3 1 2,or 2 1 3....

as i stated,this is a big project that has forms that are over 9k code so sadly i cant just copy some of the code for you guys...
however im despirately searching for methods which control the order in which the items are submitted.
the project is an accounting program and the products order in a bill of sale matters...
in short this is whats happening

```
Sales A = new A();
Foreach (var row in Datagridview.Rows)
{
//Note That the products in the datagrid are listed as 1,2,3
  A.Product = new Product{name = row.Cells[name.index].value.ToString()}
}
dc.Sales.InsertOnSubmit(A);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

//but its submitted out of order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't control the arbitrary order in which data is *stored*.  You *do* control the order in which it's sorted when you *query* and *display* that data.

You can order records with the `.OrderBy()` extension method.  Something like this:

```
var salesRecord = db.Sales.Single(s => s.Id == someId);
foreach (var product in salesRecord.Products.OrderBy(p => p.SomeValue))
    DisplayProductToUser(product);
```

Any `IEnumerable<T>` can be sorted similarly:

```
var orderedSales = db.Sales.OrderBy(s => s.SomeValue);
```

Comment: I was just in the middle of looking for confirmation on my gut feeling--nice post.

Comment: @David But i already know that,problem is when you open the Stored Data in your form to display the items,and sort them by lets say their ID,it  turns out that the items were Assigned ID's in a different order,i.e item 2 has its ID = 3,item 1 has its ID = 2,and item 1 has its ID =1 ...

Comment: @Virgil: Then sort by a different value.  Again, you *don't control* the sorting that SQL applies internally.  If you're using an auto-incrementing identity then it's guaranteed to be *unique*.  And if you commit each record in its own transaction then it's *very likely* to be in order.  However, it is not *guaranteed* to be in order (values could be reserved and released by some internal performance mechanism) nor guaranteed to be consecutive.  You're relying on a mechanism that never claimed to do what you want it to.

Comment: @David i understand,i expected wrong,thank you for the information

Comment: @David Another Question though,is entity framework the same?i mean does it not guarantee the order in which the items are submitted?

Comment: @Virgil: Correct.  This is because the order in which items are "submitted" is arbitrary.  Sorting in a database doesn't happen when you *save* the data, it happens when you *query* the data.  Sort the records when you're reading the data, not when you're writing it.